# perl regex match with numbers

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match the following (the below is in an array called @abc):

```
goo foo tool: 1.2.1 (a3 change: 234342 @ 2014/02/19 14:20:27)
```

with

```
my $match = "goo foo tool: (\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+) \(a3 change: \d+ @ #DATE# #TIME#\)";
```

and in my code,

```
 78     foreach (@abc){
 79         print "$_\n";
 80         if ($_ =~ m/$match/){
 81             print "$1\n";
 82         } else {
 83             print "not matched\n";
 84         }
 85     }
```

I am not seeing why it is printing "not matched\n";
anyone else sees why?

Comment: Because #DATE# and #TIME# are string constants.

Comment: It is not necessary to specify `$_` when you are using `m//` or `s///`.  They default to operating against `$_`.  That's why `$_` exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The #DATE# and #TIME# string constants aren't goingt to match the dates you have.  Simply adjust to regex to actually match those values:

```
my $match = "goo foo tool: (\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+) \(a3 change: \d+ \@ \d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+\)";
```

Comment: The `@` is okay only because it is followed by whitespace. If it was anything else then Perl would try to interpolate the array of that name into the string. It is safer to escape `@` in every case: `\@`.

Comment: @Borodin Agreed, that is a good practice and was one of the first thoughts I had as well when reviewing his question.  I've edited the answer to reflect that.